# MemoryError due to json encoding and decoding in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

The data that I've retrieved from database is stored as a dataFrame object `data`, and

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data_raw,columns=['col1','col2']);
```

I am trying to index the entries inside `data`.

```
json_body=data.reset_index().to_json(orient='index')
```

Then json_body is decoded and encoded

```
json_body=json_body.decode('ascii','ignore').encode('utf-8','replace') 
json_parsed=json.loads(json_body)
```

The above lines gives an error `MemoryError` .Tried to find the solution, but sadly I could not find out why such exception occurs.

Please suggest a solution to resolve this error, thanks!

Comment: How large is `data_raw`?

Comment: close to 90,000 records which are associative in nature